# Google Cloud Console - New Project's giving "invalid_client", and old projects give redirect_uri mimatch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-api-console

I have been facing the same problem from Google Cloud API Console for over a day now.

I tried to add a new redirect_uri for an old project to use it in my webapp but it gives me "redirect_uri mismatch" error. Old redirect uri still work as they used to.

I even tried creating a fresh project from the start and then registered a new application. This now gives me "invalid_client" error via google oauth.

If the old redirect_uri redirect as they should, then why doesn't the new one? Does something else need to be done when addding a new redirect uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

See [Newly created Oauth Client IDs don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064400/bug-newly-created-oauth-client-ids-dont-work/20064401#20064401) for what seems like a successful workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are all self explanatory, so you simply need to carefully retrace your steps and check typing, that you are using the correct client id with the appropriate urls.

**it gives me "redirect_uri mismatch" error.**
The uri must match character for character. eg. watch for http(s) and trailing slash

**This now gives me "invalid_client" error via google oauth.**
Either you forgot to enable the API or you haven't correctly installed the new client ID in your app.

**Does something else need to be done when adding a new redirect uri?**
NO. Just make sure it exactly matches the URL you are passing.

It's sometimes easier to switch back to the old API Console. There is a faint grey link at the bottom of the screen in the new cloud console.