# Newly created Oauth Client IDs don't work

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-console

I created a new appengine project, which creates a default web app and associated client ID. When I try to use this client ID, I get "invalid client ID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the cloud console.

To fix, I created an additional web app, which creates an additional client ID of the form 123456-randomness.apps.googleusercontent.com

The secondary client ID works.

When I go back and try the original client ID, that now works too.

Comment: I feel your pain. It is one big mess, the new cloud console. Lot of migration going on behind the scenes with the old and new consoles, oauth1 vs oauth2 and openId being deprecated.